# converting list into a matrix in Python

Tags: python, list, matrix

If you have a list of elements lets say:

```
res = 
['(18,430)', '(19,430)', '(19,429)', '(19,428)', '(19,427)', '(18,426)', '(17,426)', '(17,425)', '(17,424)', '(17,423)', '(17,422)', '(17,421)', '(17,420)', '(16,421)', '(14,420)', '(11,419)', '(9,417)', '(7,416)', '(4,414)', '(3,414)', '(2,412)', '(1,412)', '(-1,410)', '(-2,409)', '(-2,408)', '(-3,407)', '(-3,406)', '(-3,405)', '(-3,404)', '(-3,403)', '(-3,402)', '(-3,401)', '(-3,400)', '(-4,399)', '(-4,398)', '(-5,398)', '(-6,398)', '(-7,397)', '(-7,396)', '(-6,395)', '(-5,395)', '(-4,393)', '(-3,391)', '(6,384)', '(12,378)', '(24,370)', '(42,358)', '(107,304)', '(151,255)', '(207,196)', '(259,121)', '(389,-28)', '(456,-84)', '(515,-134)', '(569,-182)', '(650,-260)', '(688,-294)', '(723,-317)', '(740,-328)', '(762,-342)', '(767,-347)', '(768,-349)', '(769,-352)', '(769,-357)', '(769,-359)', '(768,-361)', '(768,-364)', '(766,-370)', '(765,-371)', '(764,-374)', '(763,-376)', '(761,-378)', '(760,-381)', '(758,-385)', '(752,-394)', '(747,-401)', '(742,-407)', '(735,-413)', '(724,-421)', '(719,-424)', '(718,-425)', '(717,-425)'], ['(18,430)', '(19,430)', '(19,429)', '(19,428)', '(19,427)', '(18,426)', '(17,426)', '(17,425)', '(17,424)', '(17,423)', '(17,422)', '(17,421)', '(17,420)', '(16,421)', '(14,420)', '(11,419)', '(9,417)', '(7,416)', '(4,414)', '(3,414)', '(2,412)', '(1,412)', '(-1,410)', '(-2,409)', '(-2,408)', '(-3,407)', '(-3,406)', '(-3,405)', '(-3,404)', '(-3,403)', '(-3,402)', '(-3,401)', '(-3,400)', '(-4,399)', '(-4,398)', '(-5,398)', '(-6,398)', '(-7,397)', '(-7,396)', '(-6,395)', '(-5,395)', '(-4,393)', '(-3,391)', '(6,384)', '(12,378)', '(24,370)', '(42,358)', '(107,304)', '(151,255)', '(207,196)', '(259,121)', '(389,-28)', '(456,-84)', '(515,-134)', '(569,-182)', '(650,-260)', '(688,-294)', '(723,-317)', '(740,-328)', '(762,-342)', '(767,-347)', '(768,-349)', '(769,-352)', '(769,-357)', '(769,-359)', '(768,-361)', '(768,-364)', '(766,-370)', '(765,-371)', '(764,-374)', '(763,-376)', '(761,-378)', '(760,-381)', '(758,-385)', '(752,-394)', '(747,-401)', '(742,-407)', '(735,-413)', '(724,-421)', '(719,-424)', '(718,-425)', '(717,-425)']
```

and we want to make all these values into a matrix where we can update values.
All these values in the list are going to be the values of the rows and columns of a matrix?
Basically:

```
row1 = '(18,430)', row2 = '(19,430)', row3 = '(19,429)',.....,rown='(717,-425)', column1 = '(18,430)', column2 = '(19,430)', column3 = '(19,429)', ..... ,columnn= '(717,-425)'
```

How can we do that in Python and later I want to update values in the rows and columns? I tried to do this where I repeat the list and make it into a matrix.
But it does not give me what I want.

```
Res_List = [res,res]
print(np.array(Res_List))
```

So I am still wondering how we can do this in Python.

I also tried:

```
mat = np.array([res,res]).T
print(mat)
```

and it kind of gives me what I want but not quite.
This gives me:

```
[['(18,430)' '(18,430)']
 ['(19,430)' '(19,430)']
 ['(19,429)' '(19,429)']
 ['(19,428)' '(19,428)']
 ['(19,427)' '(19,427)']
 ['(18,426)' '(18,426)']
 ['(17,426)' '(17,426)']
 ['(17,425)' '(17,425)']
 ['(17,424)' '(17,424)']
 ['(17,423)' '(17,423)']
 ['(17,422)' '(17,422)']
 ['(17,421)' '(17,421)']
 ['(17,420)' '(17,420)']
 ['(16,421)' '(16,421)']
 ['(14,420)' '(14,420)']
 ['(11,419)' '(11,419)']
 ['(9,417)' '(9,417)']
 ['(7,416)' '(7,416)']
 ['(4,414)' '(4,414)']
 ['(3,414)' '(3,414)']
 ['(2,412)' '(2,412)']
 ['(1,412)' '(1,412)']
 ['(-1,410)' '(-1,410)']
 ['(-2,409)' '(-2,409)']
 ['(-2,408)' '(-2,408)']
 ['(-3,407)' '(-3,407)']
 ['(-3,406)' '(-3,406)']
 ['(-3,405)' '(-3,405)']
 ['(-3,404)' '(-3,404)']
 ['(-3,403)' '(-3,403)']
 ['(-3,402)' '(-3,402)']
 ['(-3,401)' '(-3,401)']
 ['(-3,400)' '(-3,400)']
 ['(-4,399)' '(-4,399)']
 ['(-4,398)' '(-4,398)']
 ['(-5,398)' '(-5,398)']
 ['(-6,398)' '(-6,398)']
 ['(-7,397)' '(-7,397)']
 ['(-7,396)' '(-7,396)']
 ['(-6,395)' '(-6,395)']
 ['(-5,395)' '(-5,395)']
 ['(-4,393)' '(-4,393)']
 ['(-3,391)' '(-3,391)']
 ['(6,384)' '(6,384)']
 ['(12,378)' '(12,378)']
 ['(24,370)' '(24,370)']
 ['(42,358)' '(42,358)']
 ['(107,304)' '(107,304)']
 ['(151,255)' '(151,255)']
 ['(207,196)' '(207,196)']
 ['(259,121)' '(259,121)']
 ['(389,-28)' '(389,-28)']
 ['(456,-84)' '(456,-84)']
 ['(515,-134)' '(515,-134)']
 ['(569,-182)' '(569,-182)']
 ['(650,-260)' '(650,-260)']
 ['(688,-294)' '(688,-294)']
 ['(723,-317)' '(723,-317)']
 ['(740,-328)' '(740,-328)']
 ['(762,-342)' '(762,-342)']
 ['(767,-347)' '(767,-347)']
 ['(768,-349)' '(768,-349)']
 ['(769,-352)' '(769,-352)']
 ['(769,-357)' '(769,-357)']
 ['(769,-359)' '(769,-359)']
 ['(768,-361)' '(768,-361)']
 ['(768,-364)' '(768,-364)']
 ['(766,-370)' '(766,-370)']
 ['(765,-371)' '(765,-371)']
 ['(764,-374)' '(764,-374)']
 ['(763,-376)' '(763,-376)']
 ['(761,-378)' '(761,-378)']
 ['(760,-381)' '(760,-381)']
 ['(758,-385)' '(758,-385)']
 ['(752,-394)' '(752,-394)']
 ['(747,-401)' '(747,-401)']
 ['(742,-407)' '(742,-407)']
 ['(735,-413)' '(735,-413)']
 ['(724,-421)' '(724,-421)']
 ['(719,-424)' '(719,-424)']
 ['(718,-425)' '(718,-425)']
 ['(717,-425)' '(717,-425)']]
```

but what I want is the columns like how
they are designed but the rows to be the same
as the columns and that we are able to update
and put values into the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you want is a `dict`:

```py
matrix = {
    k: {l: 0 for l in res}
    for k in res
}
```

All the values are initialized to 0.

You can easily update values in `matrix`; for example, you can increase the value of a 'cell' of one:

```py
matrix['(18,430)']['(19,430)'] += 1
```

or set it to a specific value:

```py
matrix['(18,430)']['(19,430)'] = 10
```

and retrieve it:

```py
val = matrix['(18,430)']['(19,430)']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Numpy.
for converting a list to a matrix like array you should write it as list of lists (or tuples). First of all your list contain strings so we first convert strings to tuples as follow:

```
new_list = [eval(i) for i in res]
```

I used eval because your strings is in tuple form so we can tell python treat them as a chunk of code.
then lets convert this new_list to array as follow:

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.array(new_list )
```

now you can access your matrix elements as matrix[i, j] where i, j are row and column respectively. for changing a specific value of in certain location just assign it as usual:

```
matrix[i, j] = new_value
```

Comment: I did what you said and it gave me:
 [[  18  430]
 [  19  430],....,
 [ 718 -425]
 [ 717 -425]]. This is not what I want- what I wanted was to get:
                              (18,430), (19 ,430),....,(718,-425), ( 717,-425)
 (18 ,430), 
  (19 ,430),....,
  (718,-425)
  ( 717,-425)
as a matrix where I can update values.

Comment: then forget about new_list line and do the rest with your own list. maybe a good explanation of what you expect would help